# Error in if (.) else { : the condition has length > 1

Tags: r

I am trying to group my data into three categories using the ifelse function.

Consider this hypothetical dataset and the application of ifelse:

```
a <- c(2,3,3,2)
b <- c(0,1,2,3)
df <- data.frame(a,b)

df %>%
if(a>2) {
print ('Hi')
} else if (a<3 & b<1) {
print ('Hello')
} else {
print ('Bye')
}
```

This error returned when I ran the code

`Error in if (.) a>2 else { : the condition has length > 1`

How should I fix it?

Comment: `ifelse()` is vectorized, and expects a vector as input and returns a vector of the same shape as output. `if() {} else{}` is not vectorized and expects a single condition, and you can do whatever you want with it (much more flexible than "return a vector of the same shape). You want `ifelse` here, not `if`. `with(df, ifelse(a > 2, 'hi', ifelse(a < 3 & b > 1, 'hello', 'bye')))`.

Comment: What output do you expect here? `a` is a vector with four elements. The expression you are using as a logical test inside `if` is `a > 2`, which is a logical vector with 4 elements: FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE. But `if` can only check a single TRUE / FALSE at a time. That is why the error says that the condition has a length of greater than one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
df %>%
  mutate(text = ifelse(a > 2, "Hi",
                       ifelse(a < 3 & b < 1, "Hello", "Bye")))
  a b  text
1 2 0 Hello
2 3 1    Hi
3 3 2    Hi
4 2 3   Bye
```